# My RandomForest Model for StockPrognosis outputs the same value between 2 set dates

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, random-forest

I have made a RandomForest Model for Stock Prognosis. It outputs the same value everytime between 2021-11-03 and 2021-11-15. When applied to the same timeframe in 2020 it outputs it just fine.

I tried hyperparameter tuning but it just did not work as expected.

You can find the code here.
https://github.com/OfficialAnorak/RandomForestTest

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, don't have enough reputation to make this a comment instead of an answer.

Random forests cannot extrapolate beyond values seen in the training data. Once you go over the maximum value in your training data, predictions will remain constant.

See e.g. here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/235233